# Node js with typescript; How to catch express errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

So if I am using node js with javascript, I used to catch errors by adding the following code in my app.js startup file:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {   next(createError.NotFound()); });

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(err.status || 500).json({
    status: err.status || 500,
    success: 0,
    message: 'Error',
    error: [err.message],
    data: {}
  });
});
```

the "err" will be automatically caught and it will return for example 404 if I am using a route that does not exist or 500 if the database connection is not established correctly and so on.

But in typescript, how can I do the same logic?

My app.ts file is as follows

```
import express, { Application, Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
    import routes from './start/routes';
    
    const app: Application = express();
    app.use('/', require('./routes/api.route'));
    
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use('/api', routes);
    
app.use((err, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction ) => {
    res.status(err.status || 500).json({
        status: err.status || 500,
        success: 0,
        message: 'Error',
        error: [err.message],
        data: {}
    });
});
    
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(` @ http://localhost:${PORT}`));
```

this is not compiling. It says that err.status and err.message are not found. What to do?

Comment: try to use HttpException type
you may refer to this repository file
https://github.com/mwanago/express-typescript/blob/master/src/middleware/error.middleware.ts

Comment: I tried adding the required files and called app.use(errorMiddleware); but it didn't work, same error format

Comment: Can you post the specific error message?

Comment: @beautifulcoder Cannot GET /NonExistantRoute

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the type for the `err` parameter, which should be `any` according to the `ErrorRequestHandler` type.
[image: ErrorRequestHandler Type]

This will make your code compile, and the handler will run automatically when an error occurs.

To make a default response to 404 though. You will need to add another handler since it's not an error.

```
 app.use((req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction ) => { 
    // Handle not found
})
```

**NOTE** This handler should be last since it accepts every request.